# Excel custom function - lookup and concatenate matches

Tags: excel, vba

i am using a custom function that someone else built [Original Source here!](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3309-excel-vlookup-multiple-values-concatenated.html)

Code:

```
Function CusVlookup(lookupval, lookuprange As Range, indexcol As Long)
'updateby Extendoffice
Dim x As Range
Dim result As String
result = ""
For Each x In lookuprange
    If x = lookupval Then
        result = result & " " & x.Offset(0, indexcol - 1)
    End If
Next x
CusVlookup = result
End Function
```

that is working well for my purposes - except now my end user is asking for carriage returns between the results. So, for example, my initial match/concat might look like this:

```
RM_B220_L1.alm  SCIENCE - THE TEMPERATURE IN ROOM B220
RM_B220_L1.alm  HAS FALLEN 5 DEGREES BELOW SETPOINT.
RM_B220_L1.alm  THIS INDICATES A LEVEL 1 LOW TEMPERATURE ALARM
RM_B220_L1.alm  THIS ROOM CONTAINS ANIMALS AND CRITICAL RESEARCH!!
```

and thus output:

```
RM_B220_L1.alm  SCIENCE - THE TEMPERATURE IN ROOM B220 HAS FALLEN 5 DEGREES BELOW SETPOINT.THIS INDICATES A LEVEL 1 LOW TEMPERATURE ALARM THIS ROOM CONTAINS ANIMALS AND CRITICAL RESEARCH!!
```

when the end user's preference would be:

```
RM_B220_L1.alm  SCIENCE - THE TEMPERATURE IN ROOM B220 
HAS FALLEN 5 DEGREES BELOW SETPOINT.
THIS INDICATES A LEVEL 1 LOW TEMPERATURE ALARM 
THIS ROOM CONTAINS ANIMALS AND CRITICAL RESEARCH!!
```

or something similar.

now, if this was something i'd put together myself, i'd figure you could insert a character to do the carriage return between matches, but, i have *no idea* how to even begin to do that with the above code.

anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Instead of inserting `" "` between values use `vbLf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basing on the link you provided, replace the line:

```
result = result & " " & x.Offset(0, indexcol - 1)
```

with this:

```
result = result & vbCrLf & x.Offset(0, indexcol - 1)
```

vbCrLf is equivalent to putting carriage returns in vba.

Comment: i apologize, i should have included the VBA code in the original post. just occurred to me it was not fair to make you look at an outside link. i'll edit the original post to reflect the code so that anyone else that happens on this doesn't have to do that.